# Measure theory: explanation for a theorem similar to Egorov

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

---

> Let $ E$ be a measurable set with $m(E)\lt \infty$,and {$f_n$} a
>   sequence of measurable functions defined on $E$.Let $f$ be a
>   measurable (real-valued) functions such that $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$
>   for each $x\in E$.Then given $\epsilon \gt0$ and $\delta \gt0$,there
>   is a measurable set $A\subset E$  with  $m(A)\lt \delta$ and an
>   interger $N$ such that $\vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert \lt \epsilon $ $\forall
> > x\in E-A$ and all $n\ge N$.

---

***If $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ $\forall x\in E$ then since $E-A\subset E$ then it follows trivially that $\vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert \lt \epsilon $ $\forall x\in E-A$.***

Would this line of thinking be correct?

This thing has created a mess in my mind.**I want to know  what this theorem  means?What are its applications?If possible please
 explain it with the help of an example.**

I'm also looking for  some suggestions for how to go through the proof of this theorem.

THANKS!!

Comment: Please observe the difference between pointwise and uniform convergense (a.e.)! It is crucial here that, given $\epsilon >0$, the integer $N$ can be chosen such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ holds independent of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

In plain English, this theorem roughly says: "If $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ on a set $E$ of finite measure, then for sufficiently large $n$, $f_n(x)$ is close to $f(x)$ everywhere except on a small subset of $E$."

For an example, take $E = (0,1)$ and take $f_n(x) = 1/(nx)$, which converges pointwise to $f(x) = 0.$ Given $\epsilon > 0 $ and $\delta > 0$, we could pick $A = (0,\delta/2)$ and we could pick $N$ to be any integer greater than $2/(\delta \epsilon)$. Then for any $x \in E - A = [\delta / 2, 1)$ and for any $n \geq N$, we have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| = 1/(nx) < 1/(\tfrac{2}{\delta \epsilon}\times \tfrac{\delta}{2}) = \epsilon$.

I can't think of a great application off the top of my head, but I can at least come up with a proof:

Fix an $\epsilon > 0$. For each $n \in \mathbb N$, define the measurable set,
$$ A_n = \{ x \in E \ : \ | f_m(x) - f(x) | \geq \epsilon {\rm \ \ for \ some \ \ } m \geq n \}.$$
Thus
$$ A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 \supset A_4 \supset \dots $$

Since $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise, we know that for every $x \in E$, it is possible to find a sufficiently large $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $|f_m(x) - f(x) | < \epsilon$ for all $m \geq n$. Said another way: for every $x \in E$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $x \notin A_n$. Thus,
$$ \cap_{n \geq 1} A_n = \emptyset.$$

Since $m(E) < \infty$, a simple argument using countable additivity of the measure shows that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (A_n) = 0,$$
i.e. for every $\delta > 0$, there exists an $n' \in \mathbb N$ such that 
$$ m(A_{n'}) < \delta.$$

Take $N = n'$ and $A = A_{n'}$. Then $m(A) < \delta$, and
$$ x \in E - A \ \implies \ |f_m(x) - f(x) | < \epsilon {\rm \ \ for \ all \ } m \geq N.$$

Comment: In addition it might help the OP to look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420963/can-i-understand-egorovs-theorem-in-this-way?rq=1.

Comment: @BerndH Also do you know any good applications of results of this kind? If so, perhaps you could write an answer to explain?

Comment: P.S. The quantifiers in Egorov are arranged in a different order to how they are arranged here.

Comment: You're right with the quantifiers. However, I think the above stated theorem is equivalent to Egorov's. Assuming Egorov, choose $\epsilon, \delta>0$. Then $\exists A_\delta\subset E$ with $m(E-A_\delta)<\delta$ and $(f_n)\to f$ uniformly on $A_\delta$. Set $A:=E- A_\delta$ then $m(A)<\delta$ and due to uniform convergence on $A_\delta = E- A$ the existence of $N\in\mathbb N$ with $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\,\forall n>N, x\in A_\delta$ follows immediately. The other direction can be proved along the same lines.

Comment: @BerndH I agree! I think for the other direction: Fix $\delta > 0$. For any $k \in \mathbb N$, there exists an $A_k$  and  $N_k \in \mathbb N$ such that $m(A_k) < \delta / 2^k$ and $| f_m (x) - f(x) | < 1/k$ for $m \geq N$ and $x \in E - A_k$. If we now take $A = \cup_k A_k$, then $m(A) < \delta$, and $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $E - A$.