# If we have that $\mid X_n \mid$ is bounded, why is it true that $X_n \overset{a.s.}\to c$ implies that $E(X_n) \to c$ with $c$ constant?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expectation

I read in a probability book that said, without proof, that if $\mid X_n \mid$ is bounded, $X_n \overset{a.s.}\to c$ implies that $E(X_n) \to c$ with $c$ constant. Here, $X_n$ is the nth random variable of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. I know that in general this is not true without the bounded part, ie, take $X_n = n^2 Bern(\frac{1}{n^2})$, but cant see what the boundedness changes. Does anyone have any hints? Thanks!

Comment: This is just an example of the Bounded Convergence Theorem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260463/bounded-convergence-theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have

$$\lim X_n = c \ \text{a.s.}$$

let us take the expectation of both sides to get:

$$E[\lim X_n] = E[c] = c$$

Now do we have

$$E[\lim X_n] = \lim E[X_n]?$$

Note that boundedness of $|X_n|$'s means that $\exists M > 0$ s.t.

$$|X_n| \le M \ \forall n \ge 1$$

Note that $M$ is integrable $\because \ E[|M|] = E[M] = M < \infty$

By the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), we indeed have

$$E[\lim X_n] = \lim E[X_n]$$

$$\therefore c = \lim E[X_n] \ QED$$

Comment: How do I know here that the limit of $X_n$ actually exists and is finite?

Comment: @user136503 Edited

Comment: So you are saying that if I assume almost sure convergence, that naturally I am already assuming that my limit exists and is finite = $c$?

Comment: @user136503 Huh? I mean one of the hypotheses is that Xn conv as to c right?

Comment: Myb you are misunderstanding. I don't think the prop is that bounded implies as conv to a constant and further more exp is as conv to same constant. I think the prop is that bounded implies if as conv to a constant then exp is conv to same constant

Comment: In your second line when you wrote $E[\lim X_n] = E[c]=c$, I think I am a bit confused as to what allows me to take expectations under a.s. convergence. I have only taken expectations across SURELY convergent series, would you know what allows you to do that? does the expectation become an a.s. type of expectation?

Comment: @user136503 Um, if $X=Y$ a.s., then $E[X] = E[Y]$...right?